# Group by Count different values as one in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hi everyone,
I have a simple group by function where I am joining to table together and returning a count based on a status. Problem I have is I would like to count "Pending" and "Sent For Approval" under one Status like code.

i.e if "Pending" has 2 and "Sent For Approval" has 3 records then the value of the group by should be 5. "Rejected" and "Approved" should still continue working the way it was working before. "Reset" was purposefully left out.

```
`Select DISTINCT(UT.status), 
(SELECT Count(UnitRateID) 
FROM UnitRate UR join Telecom TC 
on UR.UnitOwnerID = TC.UnitOwnerID 
AND UR.WaterPeriodFrom = '".$MeterDateFrom."'
AND UR.WaterPeriodTo = '".$MeterDateTo."' 
AND TC.TelPeriodFrom = '".$MeterDateFrom."'
AND TC.TelPeriodTo = '".$MeterDateTo."' 
WHERE UR.status=UT.status
) as total
From UnitRate UT where status IN ('Pending','Sent For Approval','Approved','Rejected')
order by FIELD(status,'Pending','Sent For Approval','Rejected','Approved') ASC LIMIT 4`
```

Comment: where are you grouping?

Answer (score 1):

you can use sub sql query with a special condition like

```
select (select count(*) from table where status in ('Pending', 'Sent for approval')) as countname from table where condition
```